# How can I send the data from Google Sheets to Firebase as shown in photo?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-sheets

I need help regarding how can I send the data shown in the excel-like sheet to firebase real-time database in the structure shown in the photo below.

[image]

DATA:

Department, Year, Course-Code, Resource Name, Date-added, File-Size, File-type, Download Link

electrical, first_year, bee circuit analysis by rober l. boylestad, 10/2/2018   , 28 MB , pdf, https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1rplXzjS1LhX6MGtol679bzxp-6jtoZa4

electrical, first_year, dsa,    data structures & algorithms in 24 hours by sams    , 10/2/2018,    6 MB,   pdf,    https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1cNwRqQafn_D3-NL80S6bNUjptj8OR737

electrical, final_year, dsp solution manual of digital signal processing by proakis - (4th edition),    10/2/2018,  2 MB,   pdf,    https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1WjhcDXWcIdZyFJKL-AfEudxl4lFTjr0V

electrical, final_year, aes renewable energy resources by John twidell - (2nd Edition), 10/2/2018,  10 MB,  pdf,    https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1OMCb3G1ygg4dUGe6jc4FPE7vpGWzoEr1

This is the script i'm using to send data from google sheet to firebase 
[image]

and this is the data that is being sent to firebase using above script

[image]

Comment: Can you paste complete Google Spreadsheet information, instead of an image??

Comment: i've added the data by updating the question

Comment: So you only have 4 rows and you want to add it into firebase database , do u have any more fields in google sheet which you will add in future??

Comment: yes i will be adding similar rows in future

Comment: Try this and see if it works [link](https://www.sohamkamani.com/blog/2017/03/09/sync-data-between-google-sheets-and-firebase/) Also can you share the google sheet link you have in the img??

Comment: I have tried this but the data that is send is attached in the question above as screenshot as well as the script(code). 
Kindly check that and let me know my mistake why only last field is being sent.

Comment: The above question has been answered Here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55188513/10953546)