# Object overwritten in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Data sending from google sheet:
[image]

Script using to send data to firebase from google sheet.
    function writeData() {

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("####");
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var dataToImport = {};


for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
var department = data[i][0];
var year = data[i][1];
var course = data[i][2];

dataToImport[department] = {};
dataToImport[department][year] = {}
dataToImport[department][year][course] = {}

dataToImport[department][year][course][i] = {
            course: data[i][3],
            dateAdded: data[i][4],
            fileSize: data[i][5],
            fileType:data[i][6],
            downloadLink: data[i][7],  
          };



}
var firebaseUrl = "https:url";
var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
base.setData("",dataToImport);  

}
```

Data that is sent: 
[image]

Q: My questions that since i had parent electrical and its two childs that were 1 and 2 and each child had a course dsp and aes respectively but only 1 child is send that is the second one.

Why first child is not sent to firebase ?

Comment: Please mark ra89fi's answer if that helped your problem so that if someone comes to this question in future they would see his answer first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code replacing previous entry with new entry. Replace this -

```
dataToImport[department] = {};
dataToImport[department][year] = {}
dataToImport[department][year][course] = {}
```

with this -

```
dataToImport[department] = dataToImport[department] || {};
dataToImport[department][year] = dataToImport[department][year] || {}
dataToImport[department][year][course] = dataToImport[department][year][course] || {}
```

Comment: Thanks! a lot man, I've struggling for past 3 days to resolve this error. can you also explain what have you done in this. What's the purpose of using || ?

Comment: `||` is the javascript `or` operator. In this case it means, it there is a previous value, use that, if not, set an object `{}` as the value. This prevents overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

As a side note to [@ra89fi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4657786/ra89fi) answer (because I didn't pick up on the overwrite bug).

The line `base.setData("",dataToImport);` is **setting all data** at the **root** of your database (`""`) with the given data (`dataToImport`). Any other data in your database will be deleted.

Instead, you should use an update operation.

I unfortunately can't establish which version of the Firebase API you are using. It's not quite the REST API and not quite JavaScript. So here are some relevant documentation links.

- [REST Update Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data#section-update)
- [REST Update Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/#section-patch)
- [JavaScript (Web) Update Guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)
- [JavaScript (Web) Update Reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#update)